# Does a phase rotation introduce a delay?

Tags: discrete-signals

Suppose I have 2 complex time series, $x_1$ and $x_2$.

If I measure the delay between $x_1$ and $x_2$, I get $t$.

If I make $x_2 = x_2 e^{-j 2 \pi 10}$, and measure the delay between $x_1$ and $x_2$, do I still get $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your signal is a tone, phase rotation and time delay do the same thing.

In general, a rotation of a complex signal isn’t equivalent to a time delay.

A good portion of the beamforming literature uses the “narrow band” assumption and if the travel time of a wavefront over an array is small compared the inverse bandwidth of the envelope of the tone, beam steering (delay) is well approximated by phase multiplication.

Comment: Do you have a source you can recommend which goes over this material?

Comment: Optimum Array Processing Vol 4 by Harry Van Trees covers it. Most books on beam forming will have something on narrow band processing.  This is not an esoteric subject

Answer (score 0):

I would assume a discrete-time context (though your notation suggests continuous-time).

Then you have a misunderstanding of the relation between the "delay" and "phase". Delay is measured in *time-domain* whereas the phase rotation is defined in *frequency-domain*.

So if there was a delay $\pm d$ between $x_1[n]$ and $x_2[n]$, then $y_1[n]$ (defined as the inverse DTFT of $Y_1(\omega)$ defined below) will have zero delay wrt $x_2[n]$ in time:

$$ Y_1(\omega) = e^{ \mp j \omega d } X_1(\omega)$$

Comment: I can measure phase rotation in time domain.  Think of a QPSK modulated signal which I rotate slightly by pi/eps. I can measure this rotation by looking at the constillation in time domian.

Comment: so you don't have a misunderstanding of phase and delay then... :-)  sorry.